# Insert search input into URL redirect

Tags: wordpress, url, redirect, search

I'm creating a Wordpress page that uses the native search. I have the following PHP code in my WPCode plugin which redirects based on 2 conditions.

1. If search parameter equals a post title it will redirect to that post.
2. If no post titles exist with the search parameter it will redirect to my custom no results found page.

Code:

```
//redirects search result to exact post page
function redir_rigid_title_match() {
if (is_search()) {
  global $wp_query,$wpdb;
  $s_str = $wp_query->query_vars['s'];
  $m = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT ID FROM {$wpdb->posts} WHERE post_title = %s",$s_str));
  if (!empty($m)) {
    wp_safe_redirect(get_permalink($m));
          exit();
      }
    }
  }
  add_filter('pre_get_posts','redir_rigid_title_match');
  
  
  //redirects zero search result to add review page
    add_action('template_redirect', 'redirect_single_post');
  function redirect_single_post() {
    if (is_search()) {
      global $wp_query;
      if ($wp_query->post_count == 0) {
        wp_redirect( 'https://example.com/no-search-results/' );
        exit;
      }
    }
  }
```

Works flawlessly but I would like to include the search input in the URL redirect for condition 2 so that the https://example.com/no-search-results/ becomes [https://example.com/no-search-results/?s=[search](https://example.com/no-search-results/?s=%5Bsearch) input] when I've laded at the redirect page. So if someone searched "green cars" the url would land as https://example.com/no-search-results/?s=green+cars

I need the value of the search input for a function that is on my no search results page. Thus it needs to carry over.

Answer (score 0):

You can't make a redirect within `pre_get_posts` and **WooCommerce** already has similar stuff implemented.

Read the code on these lines to understand how WooCommerce did this, then you can write similar code for your use case: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/trunk/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-template-functions.php#L57-L65

Comment: I’m not sure we are on the same page. The code I shared already does all the redirections and works perfect. It shows the specific post and also redirects to another page when no post exists. 

I’m looking for a way to use POST or GET to carry the search criteria over to my custom “no post found” redirect page. 

Right now I’ve decided to edit the HTML on the native page that comes up when no posts are found as it carries the value over in url. I have not found a way to use my custom made “no posts found” page.